Строка типа QString в массив типа int
Нужно конвертировать строку QString в массив int.
Вот код функции:
int nonplus_numbers_sum(QString* str_a)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int size_str = str_a->size();
    int* a = new int[size_str];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_str; i++)
    {
        a[i] = str_a[i].toInt();
        if (a[i] < 0) sum += a[i];
    }
    delete[] a;
    return sum;
}

Проблема в строке a[i] = str_a[i].toInt();
При попытке скопировать первый элемент строки в первый элемент массива, в первый элемент массива копируется вся строка.

Вроде судя по документации toInt() - метод всей строки, но не символов QCharRef. Попробуй a[i] = str_a[i].tоAscii - '0';  Но символ может быть вне диапазона '0123456789'. Как вниз, так и вверх. Результат не должен быть <0 и >9. Иначе, это была не цифра.

У вас str_a это указатель, соответственно str_a[i] это первый элемент по этому указателю, то есть ваша строка. Вам надо перед взятием символа разыменовать указатель:
a[i] = (*str_a)[i].???;

Далее как указали в комментарии, toInt это метод на строке, вам же нужен метод конвертации символа в цифру, это QChar::digitValue https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchar.html#digitValue Этот метод вернет -1 если конвертация не получилась, поэтому выглядит как будто вашу проверку на < 0 надо инвертировать, если результат меньше нуля, то суммировать не надо.
А вообще чтобы не трогать указатели, рекомендую передать строку в функцию по константной ссылке и не выделять память через new, тем более что вы не возвращаете указатель, а только сумму.
Если все же надо вернуть массив, можете воспользоваться QVector или std::vector и в итоге ваш код может выглядеть примерно так:
QVector<int> toDigits(const QString& str)
{
    QVector<int> result;
    result.reserve(str.size());
    for (auto c: str)
    {
        int value = c.digitValue();
        if (value >= 0)
            result.append(value);
    }
    return result;
}

